# Scrape and store data for html display

Tags: python, html, mysql, beautifulsoup

I have coded python to scrape a webpage and retrieve listing prices.

I want to store the data and conduct a statistical analysis on the dataset.

Would this work?

**Python -> beautifulsoup -> mySQL -> html**

Data set:
$10 , $20, $10

I want to be able to calculate averages and then display them on the html page.

Answer (score 1):

You could stay in Python for the analysis (for example with Python Pandas dataframes) before storing in mySQL:
Python -> Beautifulsoup -> pandas -> mySQL -> html

Answer (score 1):

Beautifulsoup is an HTML parser. You can feed it an HTML page using Python, and extract the data you need from it. Then you can post-process the data in Python, and load it into MySQL once you're ready. I'm a bit confused about the step MySQL -> HTML, since neither is a programming language (HTML is a markup language that can't talk to MySQL, and MySQL is a database management system that can't directly output HTML), but sure, displaying MySQL data in an HTML page is a trivial step.

It might be a good idea to separate these steps a bit better, by the way. You have some code that extracts data and loads it into a database, and you have some code that displays data from the database. Keeping these two separated might increase you code quality.

Comment: As a clarification: you'll need another programming language, like Python or PHP, to take the data from MySQL and display it in HTML

Comment: Ill be getting price averages (from scrape), needing to forecast and analyse trends to then display on the html webpage

Comment: Sounds like an easy enough task to implement. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the data for normal use you can store it in sqlite db instead of mysql which has inbuilt support from python. If your site is mostly static then you can use Beautifulsoup for scraping and there are lot of python libraries like numpy for statistical analysis. If your target site has dynamically generated content then better use phantomjs or selenium driver to retrieve those contents